# inremental assign variable value from list in tcl/tk

Tags: tcl, tk-toolkit

I have a question about my work in Tcl/tk
it goes to the second row of variable called sPnflds.
New values are assigned to the variables sPn and sTitlePdf.
The other rows will work.
This process will go on until all of the rows of sPflds variable are read completely. (This process will repeat for the whole rows of sPflds list )

```
set f [open "c:/temp/labels.txt" r]
set contents [encoding convertto utf-8 [read $f]]
close $f
set labels [split $contents \n]
#puts $labels
#start of loop for first line (in labels variable)
set sPnflds [split $labels ","]
set sPn [lindex $sPnflds 0]
set sTitlePdf [lindex $sPnflds 1]
puts $sTitlePdf
puts $sPn
```

Comment: Do you want to append each `sPn` and `sTitlePdf ` to hold all occurrence ?

Comment: `encoding convertto utf-8 [read $f]` looks bad. Just use `read $f` and `fconfigure` the correct encoding onto the channel beforehand. Tcl often guesses the right thing to use anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I find your question difficult to understand. You'll have to show some of your data.

I assume you want to iterate over the lines of your file (you don't actually have a loop in your code).
I assume there are 2 comma-separated fields on each line that you want to capture into those variables.

Something like this:

```
% exec cat labels.txt
1,hello
2,world
3,foo
4,bar
% set f [open labels.txt]
file5
% set contents [encoding convertto utf-8 [read -nonewline $f]]
1,hello
2,world
3,foo
4,bar
% close $f
% set labels [split $contents \n]
1,hello 2,world 3,foo 4,bar
% foreach row $labels {
    lassign [split $row ,] sPn sTitlePdf
    puts "<$sPn> <$sTitlePdf>"
}
<1> <hello>
<2> <world>
<3> <foo>
<4> <bar>
```

You'll note I added the `-nonewline` option to read. One problem with

```
set data [read $filehandle]
set lines [split $data \n]
```

is that you get an empty line as the last element of the `lines` list. The `read` command by default gives you the data with a trailing newline. My preferred method to iterate over the lines of a file is:

```
set f [open filename]
while {[gets $f line] != -1} {
    do something with $line
}
close $f
```

It will be a little slower, assuming the file's contents fit comfortably in memory.